# DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, error-handling, dotenv

I'm trying to setup an environment for a Node.js app. but I'm getting this error every time.

> "DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file.

What does this mean and how can I solve this problem?

I'm using Windows on MAC it works fine.

Comment: did you found any solution ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env this worked for me